# netplan.io update left my vps without connection

Tags: 20.04, netplan

Doing regular updates on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS vps, one of them was netplan.io.
After that upgraded, the rest of updates failed.
This has apparently left my vps without connection. I cannot ping out or in, nor connect through ssh.
I have tried upping the network interface (was down)

```
ip link set INTERFACE up
```

and it worked but with no effect (it is up but doesnt have connection).
I still can connect and execute commands through my provider control panel.

EDIT:
Temporarily I have added the comand "dhclient INTERFACE" to /etc/rc.local in order to execute it each start and it is working. I know it is a patch but right now I can't find the issue.

Comment: Try running `sudo dhclient INTERFACE` to get an IP address.

Comment: It has worked but unfortunately it does not retain the changes after restarting.

Comment: Yeah, I have seen this once before, but it turned out that they accidentally removed netplan.io.  Makes me wonder if you need to reinstall the netplan.io package and see if that helps bring back up the network after a reboot.

Comment: I have tried doing it with "apt install --reinstall netplan.io" but it says "Reinstallation of netplan.io is not possible, it cannot be downloaded." Any other way?

Comment: Try it as a remove then install.  I have seen that before if the netplan or whatever package it is, is different than what is in the repos or it was a manual installed package.

Comment: Does *it cannot be downloaded* mean that you tried while the network was down?

Comment: Tried remove and then install but still having the same issue. I have tried setting a cron job to execute "dhclient INTERFACE" each reboot as a temporary fix but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I wonder if you are hitting something similar to this one:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046420/why-is-netplan-networkd-not-bringing-up-a-static-ethernet-interface

Comment: Temporarily I have added the comand "dhclient INTERFACE" to /etc/rc.local in order to execute it each start and it is working. I know it is a patch but right now I can't find the issue.

Comment: Please show the output of `apt policy netplan.io`.

Comment: output is: `netplan.io:
  Installed: 0.99-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 0.99-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 0.99-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
`